# remove decimals when grouping (group by) in python

Tags: python-3.x, group-by

I am generating various tables using groupby.

Here is quick example

```
tranSummary=data[data['upload_date']==Date].groupby(['tran_type'], as_index=False).agg({"Gross Loan Amount": "sum"})
tranSummary['Pct']= (tranSummary['Gross Loan Amount']/sum(tranSummary['Gross Loan Amount']))*100
```

the output is:

```
  tran_type  Gross Loan Amount        Pct
0      BB         2.604712e+10  20.059786
1      RRP        1.038003e+11  79.940214
```

Is there a trick to remove the decimals from column "Gross Loan Amount" and "Pct"?  Ideally, I would like to get the numbers rounded and remove the decimals.

many Thanks

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451189/in-pandas-can-you-aggregate-by-mean-and-round-that-mean-to-the-nearest-int

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by the link shared by Shiva. i tried `tranSummary.round(0)` which solved the rounding problem.

```
  tran_type  Gross Loan Amount   Pct
0      BB         2.604712e+10  20.0
1      RRP        1.038003e+11  80.0
```

However, I would like to remove decimals completely. I still have few zeros that shows after the decimals.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: You can try `tranSummary['Pct']= tranSummary['Pct'].astype(int)`.

Comment: thank you Jpp  it works fine. However, the example I gave is just a small illustration. I have another table with 20 columns. Do I have to convert column by column to int?  is there a shorter way of doing the conversion in one go? note that `tranSummary.astype(int)` does not work because I have some columns of type "object"

Comment: you can do `for col in col_list: df[col] = df[col].astype(int)`.. These operations are not inefficient.

Comment: let me define the column list and try it. Thank you. It is a shame that python does not recognize the float automatically